# Spring prototype bean reference in Spring @Configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-annotations

I went through the following page to bootstrap an applicationContext.xml in Java.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06.html

My applicationContext has something like:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="foo" class="com.mypackage.Foo" scope="prototype">       
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I need to refer to "foo" in Java as follows:

```
@Configuration
@AnnotationDrivenConfig 
@ImportXml("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class Config {

    @Autowired Foo foo;

    @Bean(name="fooRepository")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public FooRepository fooRepository() {
        return new JdbcFooRepository(foo);
    }


}
```

I am creating a reference of FooRepository as follows:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = 
                   new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

FooRepository fr = ctx.getBean("fooRepository", FooRepository.class);
```

Every time I invoke it, I get a new instance of FooRepository which is defined as "prototype" and this is fine with me.

But when an instance of FooRepository is returned I see the same instance of "foo" is used though "foo" in the XML file is "prototype".

1. How do I set Foo as new instance all the time to FooRepository when 
   FooRepository is created?
2. The instance of Foo should be from the XML file.

Comment: why is foo annotated with `**prototype**` instead of `prototype`? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm And can you provide the souce of Foo? is it annotated with something as well like Component?

Comment: I wanted to use the bold font for it. Actually it is just "prototype". I am editing it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the entry of `Foo` from xml. You can define it this way.

```
@Configuration
@AnnotationDrivenConfig
@ImportXml("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class Config {

    @Bean(name = "fooRepository")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public FooRepository fooRepository() {
        return new JdbcFooRepository(foo());
    }

    @Bean(name = "foo")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Foo foo() {
        return new foo();
    }
}
```

---

**Approach 2**: You can refer this [`SO Answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404253/3898076).

```
@Configuration
@AnnotationDrivenConfig
@ImportXml("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean(name = "fooRepository")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public FooRepository fooRepository() {
        return new JdbcFooRepository(context.getBean("foo", Foo.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that I don't have access to edit XML, still need to refer to the XML file to get Foo as prototype, is there a way?

Comment: I will give it a shot using approach #2 tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: @NamanGala Approach #1 should work since you are able to "override" the foo bean, Approach #2 will treat foo as singelton, so it does not.

Comment: @Zarathustra, in approach 2 foo is defined as prototype in config xml file. So everytime it will fetch new object of foo.

Comment: ah, I got it, since the @Configuration class itself is a singelton.

Answer (score -1):

**First Approach:**

Foo should be an prototype as well.

**Second Approach:**

```
@Configuration 
@AnnotationDrivenConfig 
@ImportXml("classpath:applicationContext.xml") 
public class Config {

            @Bean(name = "fooRepository")
            @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
            public FooRepository fooRepository(Foo foo) {
                return new JdbcFooRepository(foo);
            }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Foo is prototype. Please see XML sample provided.